# Deploy Office Word Add-in to office store

Tags: sharepoint, office365, officedev

The office word-in contains two projects i.e the add-in that contains the manifest file and web.

On the Microsoft [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment) there is only a step to deploy the manifest file, how do I deploy the web project? How does the manifest file reference the web project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like from your description that you are using Visual Studio to create your Word Add-in with the standard template.  Visual Studio can help you with the steps of deploying your website and updating the manifest.  Here's how:

-On the Add-in Project in Visual Studio, choose Publish.

-Create a new Publishing Profile

-Deploy the Web Project

-Return to the Publish your add-in page and choose Package the add-in.  It will give you an option to choose the location of the web project that you just published.

Detailed instructions can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/package-your-add-in-using-visual-studio